# DrawLine over GridBagLayout shows nothing

Tags: java, swing, draw, lines, gridbaglayout

I have a MapPanel class which extends JPanel. I display some objects in this grid and I want some of them to be linked by a line. So I am trying to draw this lines into MapPanel.paintComponent but I no line has been shown.
I check the line parameters (x1,y1,x2,y2) by System.out.println() and they are right ( kind of 0 < param < 600, measures that perfectly fit the panel). I also try to draw just one line with fixed parameters but I have the same problem.

```
public class NewMapPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private GameMap gameMap;
    private Grid grid;
    private JPanel contentPanel;

    public NewMapPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void updateMap(GameMap gameMap) {
        this.gameMap = gameMap;

        ...load the object into my custom object grid ...

        contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        // draw the grid
        for (City city : gameMap.getCities().values()) {
            CityPanel cityPanel = new CityPanel(city, grid);

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = grid.getColumn(city);
            c.gridy = grid.getRow(city);
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            c.gridheight = 1;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            contentPanel.add(cityPanel, c);
        }

        add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        contentPanel.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        grid.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight()); //to get the right parameters to be used into drawLine


        for (City city1 : gameMap.getCities().values()) {
            int x1 = grid.getBarycenterX(city1);
            int y1 = grid.getBarycenterY(city1);
            for (City city2 : city1.getAdjacentCities()) {
                int x2 = grid.getBarycenterX(city2);
                int y2 = grid.getBarycenterY(city2);

                System.out.println("(" + x1 + "," + y1 + ") -> (" + x2 + "," + y2 + ")");
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: We don't have the class City, please post a [mcve] that we can copy-paste and when we do so, it should compile and show your issue

Comment: Override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and `pack()` the enclosing window to establish initial geometry.

Comment: Where should I do that? And on what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the color?
g.setColor(Color.black);